# how to make a bar plot for a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, plot

I have a list of dataframes and i would like to make a barplot for each of them. In detail `sum` is the height of the bars, while `users` are the labels of each bar.

> result12

```
[[1]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D  34
2 00250902FA92  34
3 00250902FB05  34
4 002509030C41  34
5 002509030E53  34

[[2]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D  24
2 00250902FA92  24
3 00250902FB05  24
4 002509030C41  24
5 002509030E53  24

[[3]]
[1] times  users  signal mode   diff  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D   1
2 00250902FA92   1
3 00250902FB05   1
4 002509030C41   1
5 002509030E53  71
```

> dput(result12)
>   list(structure(list(users = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 13L), .Label = c("00250902DC7D", 
>   "00250902FA91", "00250902FA92", "00250902FB05", "00250902FB2E", 
>   "00250902FE0A", "00250902FE63", "002509030AD2", "002509030B9D", 
>   "002509030C41", "002509030C8D", "002509030CE4", "002509030E53", 
>   "002509030E63"), class = "factor"), sum = c(34, 34, 34, 34, 34
>   )), .Names = c("users", "sum"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
>       structure(list(users = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 13L), .Label = c("00250902DC7D", 
>       "00250902FA91", "00250902FA92", "00250902FB05", "00250902FB2E", 
>       "00250902FE0A", "00250902FE63", "002509030AD2", "002509030B9D", 
>       "002509030C41", "002509030C8D", "002509030CE4", "002509030E53", 
>       "002509030E63"), class = "factor"), sum = c(24, 24, 24, 24, 
>       24)), .Names = c("users", "sum"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
>       structure(list(times = structure(numeric(0), class = c("POSIXct", 
>       "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), users = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("00250902DC7D", 
>       "00250902FA91", "00250902FA92", "00250902FB05", "00250902FB2E", 
>       "00250902FE0A", "00250902FE63", "002509030AD2", "002509030B9D", 
>       "002509030C41", "002509030C8D", "002509030CE4", "002509030E53", 
>       "002509030E63"), class = "factor"), signal = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("false", 
>       "true"), class = "factor"), mode = structure(integer(0), .Label = c("OFF", 
>       "ON"), class = "factor"), diff = numeric(0)), .Names = c("times", 
>       "users", "signal", "mode", "diff"), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
>       structure(list(users = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 13L), .Label = c("00250902DC7D", 
>       "00250902FA91", "00250902FA92", "00250902FB05", "00250902FB2E", 
>       "00250902FE0A", "00250902FE63", "002509030AD2", "002509030B9D", 
>       "002509030C41", "002509030C8D", "002509030CE4", "002509030E53", 
>       "002509030E63"), class = "factor"), sum = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 71
>       )), .Names = c("users", "sum"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))

How can I generate automatically  my barplots?

Comment: yes it doesn't work. Probabily i write wrong the code

Comment: My fault.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the empty data frames from the list first.

```
> res <- result12[sapply(result12, dim)[1,] != 0]
> res
[[1]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D  34
2 00250902FA92  34
3 00250902FB05  34
4 002509030C41  34
5 002509030E53  34

[[2]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D  24
2 00250902FA92  24
3 00250902FB05  24
4 002509030C41  24
5 002509030E53  24

[[3]]
         users sum
1 00250902DC7D   1
2 00250902FA92   1
3 00250902FB05   1
4 002509030C41   1
5 002509030E53  71
```

And then view them all (in a pdf document) by using

```
> pdf("result12.pdf")
> lapply(1:length(res), function(i){
    barplot(res[[i]]$sum, names.arg = res[[i]]$users)
  })
> dev.off()
```

Comment: i have tried but it doesnt work...: `> lapply(1:length(result12), function(i) { barplot(result12[[i]]$sum, names.arg = result12[[i]]$users)})`      `Error in result12[[i]]$sum : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: `Result12` is a shorter version of `Pino`. i have modified my inital question to make it more convenient

Comment: I have revised it.  You need to remove the empty data frames from the list first.

Comment: yes but it create only one plot regarding the last  dataframe `result12[[4]]`.

Comment: Ok but It shows  very fast all the plots...but it's too fast...I would need to see all of them distinctly

Comment: Run the code starting from the `pdf` line, then search for "result12.pdf" on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `melt()` from the `reshape2` package to reshape the data this.  Then you can use the `ggplot2` to make the barplots.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
pino2=melt(pino,id.vars=c('users','sum'))

ggplot(pino2,aes(x=factor(users),y=sum))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+
facet_grid('L1~.')
```

`L1` is the number of the list entered, so that's what's being grouped by (if I understand you correctly).  If you don't want to do that, don't insert the `+ facet_grid('L1~.')` at the end of the ggplot line(s).

Comment: I was try to `mel` but I failed, error:  `Error: id variables not found in data: sum`

Comment: It's possible that the seventh element is causing trouble, since it has no dimensions.  Try setting `pino[[7]]=NULL`

Comment: You'd also need to get rid of pino[[3]], since it's empty, too.  that doesn't work, I'm not sure what you shoul do, since there are always columns named "sum" in those datasets.

Comment: Please check my revised answer.  It works on my end.

Comment: @user1362215 Thank u, itis perfect. Basically i need both :) Now I have to improve stuff such as the graphical effect etc..try to understand your coding...it's a miracle :)

Comment: @user1362215 Im learning your code...what are the benefits of `stat='identity'` please?

Comment: So, normally `geom_bar` will try to find the number of elements with the specific x value you assigned.  For example, if you did `ggplot(data,aes(x=Gender))+geom_bar()`, then you would get a histogram of gender.  In order to display percent values, however, you will need to use a `y=` expression in `aes`, since the default value for `geom_bar` is `stat='bin'`. Usually that will just get you a bunch of 1s and 0s in terms of bar height, which is not at all useful.